# JAAS custom login module, default CallbackHandler

Tags: java, jboss, jaas

I have custom login module in JAAS on JBoss 7, that uses custom CallbackHandler with implementation of additional Callbacks. Fragment of login module:

```
Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[3];
callbacks[0] = new javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback(...);
callbacks[1] = new javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback(...);
callbacks[2] = new MyOwnCallback(...);
callbackHandler.handle(callbacks);
```

To obtain complete information after login, aplication requires usage of MyOwnCallbackHandler which supports MyOwnCallback. Is it possible to enable login for some basic apps using built-in JBoss callback handler, i.e. org.jboss.security.auth.callback.UsernamePasswordHandler without including MyOwnCallbackHandler? One possible way to avoid UnsupportedCallbackException is to extend UsernamePasswordHandler with:

```
@Override
public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws UnsupportedCallbackException {  
    ArrayList<Callback> supportedCallbacks = new ArrayList<Callback>(callbacks.length);
    for (Callback c : callbacks) {
        if (c instanceof NameCallback || c instanceof PasswordCallback) {
            supportedCallbacks.add(c);
        }
    }
    super.handle((Callback[]) supportedCallbacks.toArray(new Callback[supportedCallbacks.size()]));
}
```

but I don't want to implement it in each application or include any additional jar.